# Node js accesscontrol package basic usage

Tags: express, npm, rbac

I am creating a node js api in which i need to implement Role Based Access Control (RBAC) in combination with Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC). I found [accesscontrol](https://github.com/onury/accesscontrol), wonderful npm package which suits my use case.

It read all the documentation which can be found here: https://onury.io/accesscontrol/?api=ac

I don't understand how to implement it, as it has few examples which only grants user roles and privileges. I don't know how to check permissions in routes modules for a specific endpoint.

I am wondering if there are any tutorials for its implementation or an example project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what you went for your rbac in the end?